# Removing a css class on buttons contained in 2 button arrays using 2 different functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

Not too sure if this is a scope problem but basically...

I have 4 div buttons in 1 array named main_btns and when you click between each, they change between 2 classes to show a different background colour by toggling.

I also have 12 buttons in another array named genre_btns that change between 2 other classes when toggled with the same change in background colour.

I need to remove the class from one array to the other when my users click between the buttons in each array. Eg: If I click one of the buttons in the genre_btns array then the background colour of a button will change, however if I click one of the buttons in the main_btns array, then the background colour of the button clicked in the genre_btns array will revert BACK while the button clicked in the main_btns will change. (Overall I need only ONE background colour to be shown when toggling buttons between each array).

here is my code:

```
<!-- array for main_btns -->
<div id="selector">
    <div id="btn-atoz" class="class2" onclick="toggleClassMainBtn(this)">
        ACTS A-Z
    </div>
    <div id="btn-headlining" class="class1" onclick="toggleClassMainBtn(this)">
        HEADLINING
    </div>
    <div id="btn-weekend1" class="class1" onclick="toggleClassMainBtn(this)">
        WEEKEND 1
    </div>
    <div id="btn-weekend2" class="class1" onclick="toggleClassMainBtn(this)">
        WEEKEND 2
    </div>
</div>

<!-- array for genre_btns -->
<div id="genre">
    <div id="btn-alternative" class="class3" onclick="toggleClassGenreBtn(this)">
      ALTERNATIVE
    </div>
    <div id="btn-blues" class="class3" onclick="toggleClassGenreBtn(this)">
      BLUES 
    </div>
    <div id="btn-country" class="class3" onclick="toggleClassGenreBtn(this)">
      COUNTRY
    </div>
    <div id="btn-dance" class="class3" onclick="toggleClassGenreBtn(this)">
      DANCE
    </div>
    <div id="btn-electronic" class="class3" onclick="toggleClassGenreBtn(this)">
      ELECTRONIC
    </div>
    <div id="btn-hip-hop-rap" class="class3" onclick="toggleClassGenreBtn(this)">
      HIP-HOP&#47;RAP
    </div>
    <div id="btn-jazz" class="class3" onclick="toggleClassGenreBtn(this)">
      JAZZ
    </div>
    <div id="btn-metal" class="class3" onclick="toggleClassGenreBtn(this)">
      METAL
    </div>
    <div id="btn-pop" class="class3" onclick="toggleClassGenreBtn(this)">
      POP
    </div>
    <div id="btn-rnb" class="class3" onclick="toggleClassGenreBtn(this)">
      R&amp;B
    </div>
    <div id="btn-reggae" class="class3" onclick="toggleClassGenreBtn(this)">
      REGGAE
    </div>
    <div id="btn-rock" class="class3" onclick="toggleClassGenreBtn(this)">
      ROCK
    </div>
</div>

<!-- css for button backgrounds -->
<style>
.class1 /* button toggles */
{
    background: #cc516d;
}

.class2 /* button toggles */
{
    background: #963B50;
}

.class3 /* button toggles */
{
    background: #cc516d;
}

.class4 /* button toggles */
{
    background: #963B50;
}
</style>


<script>
//toggles for buttons acts a-z, headlining, weekend 1, weekend 2

function toggleClassMainBtn(x){
    var main_btns = document.getElementById('selector').children;
    for(var i = 0; i < main_btns.length; i++){
        main_btns[i].className = "class1";
    }
    x.className = "class2";
}

//toggles for genre buttons 

function toggleClassGenreBtn(x) {
    var genre_btns = document.getElementById('genre').children;
    for(var i = 0; i < genre_btns.length; i++){
        genre_btns[i].className = "class3";
    }
    x.className = "class4";

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Used some jQuery.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/whu8jfe9/).

js:

```
function toggleClassMainBtn(x){
    var main_btns = document.getElementById('selector').children;
    for(var i = 0; i < main_btns.length; i++){
        main_btns[i].className = "class1";
    }
    x.className = "class2";

    $('.class4').removeClass('class4').addClass('class3');
}

//toggles for genre buttons 

function toggleClassGenreBtn(x) {
    var genre_btns = document.getElementById('genre').children;
    for(var i = 0; i < genre_btns.length; i++){
        genre_btns[i].className = "class3";
    }
    x.className = "class4";
    $('.class2').removeClass('class2').addClass('class1');
}
```